# DateTimePicker not selected in wpf

Tags: .net, wpf, ms-access

I have a database field of dateTime, I'm added a DateTimePicker Control into the window , I want that if not selected any date. Not enter anything into the database I tried the following code And it returns an error ,Does anyone have an idea?
I am working on WPF, C # and Access DB

```
try
{
    string insert_query = "INSERT INTO dbo_tasks ( Date_Created, write_From, Task_To ) " +
                          "VALUES ('" + DP_date.SelectedDate + "', " + txt_from.SelectedValue + ", " + txt_to.SelectedValue + ")";

    con1.Open();
    OleDbCommand cmd = new OleDbCommand(insert_query, con1);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
catch (Exception)
{

    MessageBox.Show("");
}
con1.Close();
```

Comment: change `catch (Exception)` to `catch (Exception e)` and `MessageBox.Show("");` to `MessageBox.Show(e.Message);`. That way you see the error.

Comment: Is `Date_Created` a nullable datetime field in the DB?

Comment: yes , if I write like this                 string insert_query = "INSERT INTO dbo_tasks ( Date_Created, write_From, Task_To ) VALUES ('" + null+ "', " + txt_from.SelectedValue + ", " + txt_to.SelectedValue + ")"; It works

Comment: As @juergen d hinted at, it would be really useful if you found out what the actual error message was...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add logic that if no date is selected then.

"INSERT INTO dbo_tasks ( Date_Created, write_From, Task_To ) VALUES ('" + null+ "', " + txt_from.SelectedValue + ", " + txt_to.SelectedValue + ")"

The problem is that DP_date.SelectedDate does not return null if no date is selected.

This will insert a null as in dbnull.  Date is a smalldatetime that accepts null

INSERT INTO [test].[dbo].[DateRange]
           ([id]
           ,[date])
     VALUES
           ('1000',null)
GO

Comment: You have an idea for such Logic?

Comment: datePicker1.SelectedDate.HasValue

Comment: Basically the answer given excellent works. But I can not get an idea of ​​how each variable would be "NULL"  not just value NULL . anybody has an idea ?

Comment: SelectedDate is null.  In a SQL insert the string null is used to represent null.  An insert statement is text so there has to be some way to represent null.  In .NET you have objects with properties like HasValue.

Comment: Sorry I did not understand, Has Value returns true / false, how do you get the string NULL?

Comment: null see the raw SQL sample in my answer